# Rails - NO CSS applied to jquery datepicker in production

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, datepicker

The Rails 4.2 application works fine with `jquery datepicker` in `development`. However the `CSS` is not applied on `datepicker` in `production` running `ubuntu 14.04`. I redeploy the application once and run the `assets precompile` a few times (also delete `assets` under `public`), the `CSS` is still not applied to `datepicker`.

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

What could go wrong with `datepicker CSS`?

Here are the configuration:

In `application.js`, it has:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
```

In 'Gemfile`, there are:

```
gem 'jquery-rails' , '<= 4.1.0'   
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

Under `assets/stylesheets`, there are:

[image]

Comment: where does the CSS for datepicker lives? when you load the prod application in the browser, look at the precompiled one big css file (through dev tools) to see if the datepicker css is included, or look at the console in dev tools to see any errors thrown

Comment: In production, the `jquery.min.css` is not loaded and it does load in development. But we do not know why `jquery.min.css` is not loaded in production.

Comment: The `jquery.ui` is loaded from CDN: <link href="http://cdn.bootcss.com/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Using `wget`, I can download the jquery-ui.min.css to the production server.

Comment: looks like, its not included during the pre-compilation. Can you post the contents of application.css.scss?

Answer (score 0):

I have the following in my application.css which will include the required jquery-ui css to serve

```
*= require jquery-ui
*= require_self
```